# Responsive design getting squeezed

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

Bearing in mind I can only try and fix this through using classes (Wordpress), does anyone know what is going wrong with this. I am trying to create a text box with a split color/photo background - this I've added through applying a class. Next I am trying to line the text up so it lays in front of the color section of the background.

This is where it goes badly wrong.

I'm designing this to be responsive so have tried using ems, vws, pc, all to no avail. Everything looks fine on the laptop screen then on the Ipad the text displays squeezed. Below where the problem is a png image of how it is supposed to look. Thanks.

Here's the page link:

http://dbtest.destinationballybunion.ie/?page_id=3458

Here are the CSS classes I'm applying to this:

```
.beachboxa {
background-image: url('http://dbtest.destinationballybunion.ie/wp-content/uploads    
/2014/09/WIDE-FISHING-BLOCK.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}

.beachboxa h3 {
font-size: 36px;
line-height: 100%;
}

.beachboxa h3 {
margin-right: 7.639em;
margin-left: 2.083em;
}

.beachboxa h6 {
font-size: 12px;
}

.beachboxa h6 {
margin-right: 17.500em;
margin-left: 6.250em;
}
```

Comment: Who says you can only change via classes? There's nothing to stop you re-arranging the divs and coming up with your own custom markup?

Comment: I'm aware that can be done but I'm new enough to using Wordpress and wouldn't feel too comfortable trying that - the last time I did try to access and alter the html it didn't go well. Can this not be solved by just using classes ?